# Javascript to compare two XSL values

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I'm trying to validate an xsl value against another xsl value, ( minimum/maximum values which are stored in the XML using Javascript ( it has to be JS),And i can't use the nice and easy HTML 5 validation method, yay! and i can't figure out how to do it.

The XSL is as follows ( this pulls my value correctly)

```
 <xsl:attribute name="test1">
      <xsl:value-of select="data/object/object/object/property/property/property/format/@answer"></xsl:value-of>
   </xsl:attribute>
```

This is the XSL that pulls in the minimum value,

```
 <!-- Min Value-->
 <input type="hidden" name="minvalue">
 <xsl:attribute name="value">
 <xsl:value-of select="/options/@minimum"></xsl:value-of>
 </xsl:attribute>
</input>
```

I was hoping to Use either the Input types themselves or the name values to compare against, but all i can find is html 5 validation and i need it this odd this >.<

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be awesome ( PS first time so sorry for any code formatting issues etc)

Comment: Where are you trying to validate this?  Within the stylesheet itself, using a custom JavaScript extension functoin?  On an HTML web page in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to do this in XSLT, you could try to do something like this...  Assuming these things fall in the same template anyway.

```
<xsl:variable name="test1" select="number(data/object/object/object/property/property/property/format/@answer)" />

<xsl:variable name="minimum" select="number(/options/@minimum)" />

<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$test1 > $minimum">
     <!-- output whatever you want here because the condition is satisifed -->
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <!-- output for when condition is not satisfied -->
  </xsl:otherwise> 
</xsl:choose>
```

There are otherw ays to do this if you share your full XSLT - perhaps having templates structured such that they only match on these conditions.  There are also ways to do it in JavaScript on an HTML page, but we'd need to see your final output rather than your XSLT for that.